# Call Snowsql procedure via shell script

Tags: shell, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to call a Snowflake procedure via shell script. For that I need to

1. connect to my data warehouse
2. call my procedure

Here's my .sh file:

```
#bin/bash
BASE_DIR=/opt/analytics
JOBS_DIR=$BASE_DIR/jobs

#call snowsql proc
snowsql -q CALL calculateduration();
```

I have configured my Snowflake connection parameters in the config file, so I do not need any arguments to connect to the data warehouse, such as `snowsql -a -u -d`

To connect, i simply type `snowsql`

What my shell script should do is

1. command: snowsql
2. call calculateduration() which is in a file e.g. durations.sql;

In Postgres it would be something like this

```
psql -U user -d db -f "$JOBS_DIR/sql/calculatedurations.sql"
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to make it work with Snowsql.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your error? What is not working?

Comment: Hi @Marcel it does connect to the database but it does not call the procedure. I tried with storing the procedure in a file and it works snowsql -f "$JOBS_DIR/dbscripts/calculatedurations.sql"

Comment: The argument to `-q` should be fully quoted, such that its a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this...

I was able to make this work by storing my procedure call in a file and executing that file with the -f arguments that snowsql offers.

My .sh file

```
#bin/bash
JOBS_DIR=$BASE_DIR/jobs

#call snowsql proc
snowsql -f "$JOBS_DIR/dbscripts/calculateDurations.sql"
```

Comment: I think Dan's comment should be the answer to your original question, this is just an alternative. If could have helped if you share exactly what the original error message was.

Answer (score 0):

Using full qualified identifier should do the trick. So please try to add Database as well as Schemaname in front.